# Retrieve strings from a file, filtering with Linq when multiple lines contain the exact same string

Tags: c#, linq, morelinq

I am using Visual Studio, with the NuGet package MoreLinq for my following solution.

Example contents of a file that I wish to retrieve, the file also contains other irrelevant data:

```
...
#define HELLO
#include "hello.h"

code

#define BYE
#include "hello.h"
...
```

My attempt at the solution, which does almost exactly what I want. But only almost, and I can see why, that's logical:

```
var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, ".", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".c") || s.EndsWith(".h"))
            from line in File.ReadLines(file)
            .SkipWhile(l => l.TrimStart() != ("#define HELLO"))
            .TakeUntil(l => l.TrimStart() == ("#define BYE"))
            .ToList()
            select new
            {
                File = file,
                Line = line
            };

foreach (var f in files)
{
    sotredLines.Add(f.Line.Trim());
}
```

At this point my solution would give me the following results:

```
#define HELLO
#include "hello.h"

code

#define BYE
```

If you didn't notice, it is missing the last line that I also wanted to retrieve -> **#include "hello.h"**. My attempt at solving this problem was to add the following line to the code

```
...
.SkipWhile(l => l.TrimStart() != ("#define HELLO"))
.TakeUntil(l => l.TrimStart() == ("#define BYE"))
.TakeUntil(l => l.TrimStart() == ("#include \"hello.h\""))
...
```

But this (as expected) returned only the following results:

```
#define HELLO
#include "hello.h"
```

Completely ignoring the rest of the wanted information. Because **#include "hello.h"** appears multiple times, and it stops at the first one that was found.

I want to retrieve only these lines from the mentioned file, without missing one of the lines:

```
#define HELLO
#include "hello.h"

code

#define BYE
#include "hello.h"
```

**For the solution, whilst still using Linq, see @Freggar's answer below.**

Comment: I don't understand what you really want. Do you want to include the line after `#define BYE` or do you want the last `#include "hello.h"`? You are trying the first and asking for the second.

Comment: @Freggar I want the line after `#define BYE` to also be included in the results.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? linq may not be the answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set a flag in `TakeUntil` that indicates that you are past `#define BYE`:

```
bool byeFlag = false;
var p = from line in File.ReadLines(file)
        .SkipWhile(l => l.TrimStart() != ("#define HELLO"))
        .TakeUntil(l =>
        {
            bool ret = byeFlag;
            if (l.TrimStart() == "#define BYE")
            {
                byeFlag = true;
            }
            return ret;
        })
        .ToList()
        select new
        {
            File = file,
            Line = line
        };
```

---

But as already mentioned, maybe LINQ is not really the best tool for what you are trying to do. Maybe parsers like [ANTLR](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4) are better suited for the job?

Comment: I stumbled upon ANTLR and similar parsers whilst I was looking for a solution. But for now I solved it and will look more into other solutions. I was also not aware that it was possible to do what you have done within the Linq functions. Very thankful for that!